# Help page "Edit questions and answers" lists incorrect value for "Awarded at"

Tags: discussion

Our Help page "[Help Center > Privileges > edit questions and answers](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)" says: "Awarded at: 1,000 reputation", that's incorrect; I have the Badge and believe it's awarded at 500.

Also at the bottom of the page it says: "In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing [suggested edits](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) (which previously you would have had to suggest)." **and** "the [low quality posts](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts) queue is also made available", but for those privileges you do need 1000 rep according to the pages they link to.

**If** the page is a temporary Template and it's planned to bump it up in the future, once we gain a large enough base for the queue (to avoid overburdening a few people), could we simply change the rep number and one line:

"**Reviewing suggested edits**"

"**Reviewing suggested edits** - The following is awarded at 1000 reputation"

Not to be pedantic, but accuracy equals credibility (in addition to other attributes).

Comment: What happens when you try to edit the answer to this post? Does it show you an error “suggested edits are not allowed for non-tag wiki pages”? If so you don’t have full editing privileges anymore as heather wrote.

Comment: @MEE - It's main.

Comment: if you have full editing privileges in main you have them in meta and vice versa. Can you edit posts or only suggest edits (in main)?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the site recently switched from private to public beta. The reputation levels at which privileges are awarded change, because as the site grows (from private to public to graduate) it is more important that only high-rep users get privileges (as they are trustworthy).

Also, at private beta, very few questions have been asked and there are no mods, so to get anything done it's important that rep levels are low. They get a little higher at public beta, and are at their highest when the site graduates.

### Tl;dr, it isn't inaccurate, just reflecting us getting bigger.

Comment: Did I explain that in my question or does your answer offer new information? --- TL;DR Huh?

Comment: @Rob In private beta it was awarded at 500 rep. However, in public beta, it's awarded at 1k rep, so you won't be able to edit (other than suggest edits) until you get to 1k rep now

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 - My Stats say that the Editor Badge was: "Awarded Mar 26 at 7:18". The Badge was not revoked. If I spot something legitimately needing an edit before I hit 1K then I'll make an update.

Comment: @Rob the editor badge is awarded for the first edit you make and can be awarded even if you make a suggested edit that's accepted. You can always suggest edits regardless of rep, at which point it goes into the suggested edits queue. Making suggested edits is definitely encouraged! (if the edit is helpful in some way, obviously)